# C strlcat implementation

Tags: c, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

I have to reproduce some basic functions in C and one of them is strlcat.

After reading the man and testing the strlcat from `<bsd/string.h>` library, I wrote the following code which seems to be a working copy of the function:

```
#include <string.h>

size_t  ft_strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
    size_t  lsize;
    size_t  dsize;

    lsize = 0;
    dsize = strlen(dst);
    while (*dst && size > 0 && size--)
    {
        dst++;
        lsize++;
    }
    while (*src && size > 1 && size--)
        *dst++ = *src++;
    if (size == 1)
        *dst = '\0';
    return (dsize + lsize);
}
```

Is this implementation missing something?

Comment: This would be easier to review if you linked to the `man` page on the internet and quoted the most important parts here.  It seems like `strlcat` keeps up to the first `l` characters from the combined destination and source strings.  There are oddities here that may or may not be intended.

Comment: Here is the man: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcat&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+6.2-RELEASE the most important part is the return value, it has to be right

Answer (score 3):

Using [freebsd strlcat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcat&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+6.2-RELEASE) as a guide.

1. "length" with C strings typical does not include the null character.  "size" usually *does* include the null character.  Suggest name change

   ```
   // dsize = strlen(dst);
   dlen = strlen(dst);
   ```
2. Code walks the array and repeatedly adjust 3 variables.  Could be done adjusting only 2.

   ```
   while (*dst && size > 0 && size--) {
       dst++;
       lsize++;
   }
   // vs.
   size_t remaining_size = size;
   while (*dst && remaining_size > 0) {
     dst++;
     remaining_size--;
   }
   size_t lsize = size - remaining_size;
   ```
3. The below could use `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`.  These functions are typically optimized for speedy execution, especially long strings.  The *key performance assessment should be based on long strings and with sufficient space.*  Little need to optimize for undersized values of `size`.

   ```
   while (*src && size > 1 && size--)
     *dst++ = *src++;
   // vs.
   memcpy(dst, src, ...);
   ```
4. Code does not handle overlapping strings.  Should use `restrict` to indicate that.

   ```
   size_t ft_strlcat(char * restrict dst, const char * restrict src, size_t size);
   ```
5. Pedantic code would test for overflow in `dsize + lsize`, but let us skip that corner case for now.
6. Initialize when declaring, if possible.

   ```
   // size_t  lsize;
   // lsize = 0;
   size_t  lsize = 0;
   ```

Some lightly tested code follows.

```
size_t ft2_strlcat(char *restrict dst, const char *restrict src, size_t size) {
  size_t s_length = strlen(src);
  size_t remaining_size = size;

  while (*dst && remaining_size > 0) {
    dst++;
    remaining_size--;
  }
  // Length of destination is the lesser of `size` and 
  // offset of the null character, if any. 
  size_t d_length = size - remaining_size;

  if (d_length < remaining_size) {
    // We know there is at least room to write the \0

    size_t copy_length = remaining_size - 1;
    if (s_length < copy_length) {
      copy_length = s_length;
    }
    memcpy(dst, src, copy_length);
    dst[copy_length] = '\0';
  }
  return d_length + s_length;
}
```

Comment: I do like how you simplified and optimized the code but there is one problem. The return value is not right, you return the src length + dst length, the man says "The strlcpy() and strlcat() functions return the total length of the
     string they tried to create." So there should be returned the len of the new string and if no string is created it should return the src len.

Comment: @UnixCode Disagree. [For strlcat() that means the **initial** length of dst plus the length of src.](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strlcat).  Provide link to your man page.

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcat&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+6.2-RELEASE

Comment: I just tested the code you provided with the original strlcat from bsd and the return value differs. Please check maybe I am worng

Comment: The issue is this "Note however, that if strlcat() traverses size characters without finding  a NUL, the length of the string is considered to be size and the destination string will not be NUL-terminated (since there was no space for the  NUL)."  I'll look at that later.

Comment: Also found a bug in my code apparently if size <= src the src len has to be returned not the dst. Will come back with some code

Comment: Note: best not to change the original code at this site.  You can post your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Minor loop edits

Your first loop has a bit of a strange condition:

> ```
>     while (*dst && size > 0 && size--)
>     {
>         dst++;
>         len++;
>     }
> ```

If `size > 0` is true then `size--` must always be true as well.  So instead of adding `size--` as a third condition, I would put it in the loop:

```
    while (*dst && size > 0)
    {
        dst++;
        len++;
        size--;
    }
```

Your second loop has the same kind of construct:

> ```
>     while (*src && size > 1 && size--)
>         *dst++ = *src++;
> ```

In this case, since the condition is `size > 1`, we can just simplify to this:

```
    while (*src && size-- > 1)
        *dst++ = *src++;
```

This change wasn't possible for the first loop because `size-- > 0` would allow size to reach -1, which would be bad because `size` is an unsigned type, and you use its value in the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be working fine (updated!):

```
size_t  ft_strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
    size_t  len;
    size_t  slen;

    len = 0;
    slen = strlen(src);
    while (*dst && size > 0) // added @JS1 edit
    {
        dst++;
        len++;
        size--;
    }
    while (*src && size-- > 1) //added @JS1 edit
        *dst++ = *src++;
    if (size == 1 || *src == 0) // **VERY IMPORTANT:** read update below
        *dst = '\0';
    return (slen + len);
}
```

I also renamed the variables as suggested.
I tried to implement memcpy but that needs 2 extra variables and an other strlen call.

Tests:

My function

./a.out abc efgh 0

Concatenated string:abc 
Return value:4

./a.out abc efgh 5

Concatenated string:abce 
Return value:7

./a.out abc efgh 7

Concatenated string:abcefg 
Return value:7

./a.out abc efgh 8

Concatenated string:abcefgh 
Return value:7

./a.out abc efgh 9

Concatenated string:abcefgh 
Return value:7

Bsd function:

/a.out abc efgh 0

Concatenated string:abc 
Return value:4

./a.out abc efgh 5

Concatenated string:abce 
Return value:7

/a.out abc efgh 7

Concatenated string:abcefg 
Return value:7

./a.out abc efgh 8

Concatenated string:abcefgh 
Return value:7

./a.out abc efgh 9

Concatenated string:abcefgh 
Return value:7

It seems right now, please if you have any other suggestions or more simple methods post it.

**Update:**

After running tests this with big sizes: ./a.out abc efgh 102910 | cat -e

the output was strange:

Concatenated string:abcefgh**M-^?** $

Return value:7 $

This was fixed by forcing the Terminator char by adding the condition *src == 0 to the if statement

Comment: Man used: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcat&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+6.2-RELEASE

Comment: The `while (*src && size-- > 1)  *dst++ = *src++;` does not need to test `*src` in the loop as `size` and `slen`  are known prior and an adjustment to `size` could first be determined before the loop.